# We'd like math support enabled

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Some Stack Exchange sites, such as Math and Physics, allow LaTeX equations for rendering in questions and answers. For example, writing

```
$\frac{f_{MHz}}{300} \times \frac{1}{2.54}$
```

would result in (approximately)

```
 f
  MHz     1
----- * -----
 300    2.54
```

Since it's easy to conceive of amateur radio-related questions which include math in the question as well as in the answers, **it seems like having access to this feature would be a really nice thing on ham.SE.**

How does the community feel about having that feature enabled?

---

...and then we end up with question titles like...

[image]

Comment: +1 I love to misuse that feature for tables.

Comment: Yup. Our FAQ will be full of those ascii tables if we don't have math support :D

Comment: @JohannesKuhn If you grok LaTeX tables, I'd almost say you deserve the right to do that! :)

Comment: $\begin{array}{cc}Because&I\\love&tables\end{array}$ -- Will be rendered later.

Comment: **Administrative Note** — The best way to get MathJax enabled is to demonstrate a *need* for it by citing questions which would be improved with the feature. See how it was done (for example) on [Space Exporation](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/q/7/68) and [Astronomy](http://meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/10/58).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are numerous examples of questions which would or could be better asked, or answered, with math support available. A few that I found just quickly browsing through the site's current questions are:

- [Why is the speed of light rounded to 286 Mm in calculations involving frequencies below 30MHz?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/325/why-is-the-speed-of-light-rounded-to-286-mm-in-calculations-involving-frequencie) (answered without math, but the question explicitly requests the math as well)
- [Calculating Antenna Length on the FCC Exam vs. in Reality](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/283/calculating-antenna-length-on-the-fcc-exam-vs-in-reality) which has several formulas currently included as an image straight into the question and both current answers include formulas
- [How to calculate the peak-to-peak voltage of a sine wave given RMS voltage](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/278/how-to-calculate-the-peak-to-peak-voltage-of-a-sine-wave-given-rms-voltage) which seems to cry out for a math-based answer
- [How do I determine antenna spacing?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-determine-antenna-spacing) the current answer for which includes several "mathy" references and formulas
- [What gain do I need to talk to SO-50 with my HT?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/316/what-gain-do-i-need-to-talk-to-so-50-with-my-ht) the answer to which is heavy on math due to propagation and link budget calculations
- [Phasing harness for antenna array](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/256/phasing-harness-for-antenna-array), as making up a phased array of any sort of antenna is pretty math-heavy, could probably benefit in the answer section from having math support available to incorporate the relevant formulas
- [What is a link budget, and how do I make one?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/352/what-is-a-link-budget-and-how-do-i-make-one) (full disclosure: this question is my own)

In addition, as I browsed through my copy of *The ARRL Handbook for Radio Amateurs* (year 2002 edition, if you must know), I had to flip the book to five pages completely at random before I came upon one with mathematical formulas plainly visible. The next page in that book which I flipped to had a large table spread out over two pages. It took two more random page flips before I came upon some more mathematical formulas. *The ARRL Antenna Book* had a few tables on the first random page I opened it to, and by the time I'd flipped pages five times I came across a page that had several diagrams and numerous formulas. *While these aren't questions asked on the site*, these books are common reference works in the amateur radio field and I see no reason to not expect such material to make it into both questions and answers on this site on a regular basis.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Makes the "argument" easier.

Comment: Yes I just copied and pasted screenshots from LaTeX for [my answer on that one as well](http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/283/calculating-antenna-length-on-the-fcc-exam-vs-in-reality/330#330).

Comment: @RobertCartaino I added a few more, and made the answer Community Wiki to encourage others to add even more links. (I hesitate to use the abbreviation CW here because it means something completely different in amateur radio. :))

Answer (score 14):

Yes. There's enough math-based discussion in the ham community that it'd be useful.

Comment: Agreed. The hobby has a very mathematical side to it.

Comment: YES!!! Great proposal....

Answer (score 2):

It's here!

$\frac{\pi{}}{16}(\sqrt{1+cos^2(\frac{\pi{}}{32})} + \sqrt{1+cos^2(\frac{3\pi{}}{32})} + ... \sqrt{1+cos^2(\frac{15\pi{}}{32})}) = 1.91009889$

$\Bbb Z[\sqrt 3]\cong \frac{\Bbb Z[x]}{(x^2-3)}$

$$\int_0^e x^{1/x}dx=2e\sum^\infty_{n=0}\sum^n_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{e^nk!}$$

w00t!

Comment: Great... Now to figure out how to use it xD

Comment: @Seth Never mind how to use it; figure out what Dan is talking about instead! :D

Comment: And you can even use it in edit comments... check the history on this one!

Comment: @MichaelKjörling sweet! thanks